# Setting array to JTextField then removing

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, keylistener, settext

I am wanting to get a JTextField filled with an array A-Z. Then when a user pressed e.g. P on the keyboard, that letter will be removed from the JTextField.

So far all I have is the following, I know it's nowhere close so apologies (And I know it wont work).

```
tf_1 = new JTextField();
String[] alphabet = {"A", "B" //etc};
tf_1.setText(alphabet);
tf_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  // Remove letter if typed.
 }
}
```

Inside the key listener, how can I add code to remove the typed letter from the alphabet array?

Comment: `setText` doesn't accept an array as a parameter. It accepts a `String`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I know that, I said in the text I know it doesn't work. I'm just trying to show what I am trying to do rather than giving no code at all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so fine, but works

```
//Frame maninFr = new Frame();
JTextField tf_1 = new JTextField();
//maninFr.add(tf_1);
//maninFr.show();

String[] alphabet = {"A","B"};
tf_1.setText(Arrays.toString(alphabet));
tf_1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  String input = tf_1.getText();
  char pressed = e.getKeyChar();
  String newInput = input.replaceAll(Character.toString(pressed), "");
  System.out.println("pressed: " + pressed);
  System.out.println("newin : " + newInput);
  tf_1.setText(newInput);
 }

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is quite close to what I need, I'll give it a try and get back to you :D

Comment: Enjoy, welcome :) Btw I will be better approach to use special box for input or something I think. I just noticed you will have two text fields, then it will be better to implement lost focus if there is something like that, and you can allow the whole strings to replace

Answer (score 0):

I hope your requirement is to listen to the key input event and remove, entered character from alphabet array. Please check following code.

```
JTextField tf_1 = new JTextField();
String[] alphabet = { "A", "B" };
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alphabet));
tf_1.setText(alphabet.toString());
tf_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
    int id = e.getID();
    String keyString;
    if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED)
    {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      keyString = c+"";
      for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
      {
        if (alphabet[i].equalsIgnoreCase(keyString))
        {
          list.remove(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is pretty much close enough ,I was wanting it so the array is set in the text tf1, then when they type say "A" in a separate textfield e.g. tf2 it will be removed from the array and tf1 will be updated :D

Comment: You can add the listener to tf2 and call setText method of tf1 within it.